# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a ASP.NET application that connects to a SQL server backend on another server. At random points throughout the day I will get a message when logging into the application that states:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This may happen 2-3 times per day and will last about 30 minutes or so. The everyting will run fine for a few more hours until it happens again. The crazy thing about it is that I cannot even ping the server using its hostname while this error is occurring. I can ping it by the IP address though. Once the web application can connect again I can ping the server again by its hostname.

Even stranger is that I have another web application that is running on the same webserver and uses the same SQL server database as a backend that continues to function while the other web application is generating the error.

Each application is running on a different application pool on IIS 6 (Recyclying the affected app pool does not appear to resolve the problem). Both applications run on .NET 4 and the webserver is Windows Server 2003. The database is running on SQL Server 2008.

Any ideas what my issue could be?

Comment: Maybe DNS? Is the Connection String in your app a hostname, and that uneffected app using the IP?

Comment: I am beginning to think it may be DNS related. I was referencing the server by hostname in the connection string. I just changed it to use the IP address and it worked almost instantly. It is strange that the hostname sometimes works, and then I few minutes later it doesn't. I'm sure it is better practice to use the IP over the hostname anyways.

Comment: If the other web app keeps running while you can't ping the db server by it's hostname, it doesn't use the same connectionstring does it?

Comment: Correct, it does not use the same connection string. The other application uses the IP address so I guess that is why it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a DNS issue, and it probably has nothing to do with your code. Can you use the IP address in your connection string instead?

Comment: Yes, I updated the connection string to use the IP address and it seems to have resolved the issue. Strange that the hostname works most of the time though.