# windows 10 cannot connect to sql server database in visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

I've been having a problem using Visual Studio Community 2015 to connect to a networked sql server with a networked user, a local administrator, and a domain administrator.

Here's the connection string in Visual Studio:

```
string connecitonstring = "Server=development;Database=testdb;User Id=TestUser;Password=TestPassword;";
conn = new SqlConnection(connecitonstring);
```

1) Running Visual Studio as non-administrator and as an administrator, I get the following error.

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

2) Without changing any code and running VS as a domain administrator I get a successful connection.

Compiling and running the application as a non-administrator has a successful connection.

Comment: <strike>You may need to create a named pipe. ODBC is another popular way to connect if you are willing to consider a different means of connecting. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx</strike> sorry I didn't see `2)` it seems to be a permissions thing. Try changing your permissions on the named pipe

Comment: Search this site for `[sql-server]` + the first 10 words of that error message. This question has been asked (and answered) several times in the past.

Comment: IP Address instead of the Named Pipe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066749/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Milo (+1), it was a permissions problem on the file server.  Ken -1 for you, please assume that those resources are exhausted.  There was no answer on this site that discusses the below.

The problem is the source code was being executed from a secured shared location.  Where AD/Visual Studio had a problem resolving (not sure why, and beyond the scope of this question).  I moved the source code to a local directory, and then into a shared network directory that does not have permissions defined and the project runs fine on both accounts.